# Need help about using git and bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I created a repository in bitbucket. Now i am going to write a java project in my computer. The problem is, what should i do to put files in bitbucket? In other words, am i going to write my program in eclipse, and then copy the .java files to the project folder in my computer, and then use **git add** and **git commit** commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Repository in bitbucket. When you get to the last screen it will ask if you want to import an existing project.
Select import and it will give you the commands to type on your machine to create a 'remote' and the command to push the changes out to the remote bitbucket repository.

More details at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Importing+code+from+an+existing+project#Importingcodefromanexistingproject-Importanexisting,unversionedcodeprojecttoanemptyrepository

Comment: Thanks, so it is just like this: you write the code in your computer, and then just import it to bitbucket, you do not do any changes on code on bitbucket, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push it..

git remote add origin git@git:Projectname.git

git push -u origin master